# AttributeError: Menu instance has no attribute '__len__'

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am not familiar with the ways of python, i saw few other questions here with similar description, but could not fix this.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/UT/PycharmProjects/tkinter/python_PET/main.py", line 16, in <module>
    m = menu_bar_class(root)
File "C:/Users/UT/PycharmProjects/tkinter/python_PET/main.py", line 14, in __init__
    self.master.config(self.menu)
File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1326, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1312, in _configure
    cnf = _cnfmerge(cnf)
File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 114, in _cnfmerge
    for c in _flatten(cnfs):
AttributeError: Menu instance has no attribute '__len__'
```

Program:

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog import *
import tkMessageBox
import ttk
root = Tk()

class menu_bar_class:

    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master
        print("menu bar")

        self.menu = Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(self.menu)

m = menu_bar_class(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass in the menu as a keyword argument:

```
self.master.config(menu=self.menu)
```

When you pass in a *positional* argument (so without the `menu=` part), then Tkinter expects to receive either a dictionary with configuration (so `{'menu': self.menu}`) or a sequence containing more sequences or dictionaries. Because `self.menu` is neither, you get the error you see.